# How to change Windows sleep time to something > 5 hours?

Tags: windows, windows-11, sleep

Windows 11 settings allow different intervals until the PC is put to sleep due to inactivity. 5 hours is the longest duration. I'd like to configure my PC to go to sleep after a day's inactivity, but this isn't allowable via the settings at least.

I'm assuming (hoping?) there's something in the registry that can be edited to allow an interval greater than 5 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following commands to set the sleep timeout to any
number of minutes:

```
powercfg /change standby-timeout-ac (minutes)
powercfg /change standby-timeout-dc (minutes)
```

The parameter `standby-timeout-ac` relates to mains power,
and `standby-timeout-dc` to battery.

Here is what happens after running `powercfg /change standby-timeout-ac:21600`:

---

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this might be an issue here, but *some* Windows timeouts ignore settings greater than a hard-coded limit, so test that the higher setting works.

Comment: Worked well for me, but worth noting that I believe ac is for wired and dc is for battery. At the least, I had to update ac on my desktop to get it to work.

Comment: You're right - I got them crossed. Fixed in the answer.